Why am I unable to see Yamux protocol in my Wireshark settings?
I've been trying to analyze network traffic that uses the Yamux
(Yet another Multiplexer) protocol via Wireshark, but I'm having trouble finding Yamux listed in the protocol settings or able to decode any packets.
Here are the steps I've taken so far:
Checked the available protocols under the "Preferences" menu but couldn't locate Yamux.
Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to install a specific plugin or script to enable Yamux protocol support in Wireshark?

I haven't tried it, but does wireshark-consul-dissector help? The readme contains A Wireshark dissector for HashiCorp Consul and HashiCorp Yamux, written in Lua..

Hi, thanks for the link. I followed the instructions mentioned in the README but no luck. I tried using the filters as well but again I don't see anything.

When you mention "I followed the instructions mentioned in the README but no luck" did you get any errors? I tried following the instructions and with Wireshark version 4.2.2 got the error attempt to call field 'prepend_path' (a nil value) after installing the plug-in - see Wireshark support for Yamux protocol. Will try and investigate if a code change is needed to allow the plug-in work.
